# Why I can't get 2A current?

Tags: power-supply

[image]
[image]
[image]

The Power Supply type is : GPD-3303D:
https://www.gwinstek.com/en-global/products/downloadSeriesSpec/1476
https://i-item.jd.com/40560962477.html

I serial the two 25V power supply to 50V.

the output voltage is 45V, not 50V meausred with multimeter.
When the current is higher thant 1A , the red led on the Power supply will turn on.

Comment: 50 V and 50 ohms means 1A.

Comment: The 40 ohm is adjustable resistor

Comment: ROFL And if you drew a legitimate schematic, we have some chance of helping you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the current limit(s) higher. Your power supplies are going into constant-current mode.

Comment: Thankyou, after set the current limit to 3A, the problem solved!